# In pyspark, how to use a loop with the withcolumn function to add a variable number of columns to the dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark, using the withColumn function, I would like to add to a dataframe a fixed column plus a variable number of columns, depending on the size of a list.
I tried doing this by creating a loop before the withColumn function. This solution doesn't deliver the expected result as only the last column in the loop is added to the dataframe (made persistent). I understand that adding a loop before the Window function would deliver the expected results, however executing the Window function many times would kill my process - performance wise -, as my dataset has millions of records and the list has a large number of items.

```
...
products = ['a','b','c']
w1 = Window.orderBy("ID").partitionBy("ID")
data = data.withColumn(
        "ID_changed_column",
        (f.col("ID") != f.lead("ID").over(w1)).cast("int")
        )
for product in products:
      data = data.withColumn(
        product,
        ("boo")
        )
...
```

In this example, I need to add to dataframe 'data' 4 columns: 'ID_changed_column', 'a', 'b' and 'c'. With the above code, I only get column 'c' (the last one on the loop). Is there any solution using the Window function only once?

Comment: replace this line of code data = data.withColumn( product,  lit("boo")) (otherwise gives errors), you should see all cols.

Comment: @RangaVure, thanks, but if I replace that line of columns, I wont get columns 'a' to 'c' added to the dataframe. The good news is that after additional testing, the above code does work. The problem was with extracting data from the resulting dataframe.